# Rotate multiple SVG layers in different directions using just CSS Hover

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations, markup

I'm attempting to rotate SVG layers in different directions when a user hovers over the image. I can easily rotate the div container but of course this rotates the entire image. I've made a start on the code and hoping that one of you bright sparks familar with SVG animations can help me in the right direction. If possible I'd like to avoid SVG SMIL or JavaScript solutions.

Here is my **HTML Code**:

```
<div class="services-one">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="35px" height="35px" viewBox="0 0 35 35" enable-background="new 0 0 35 35" xml:space="preserve">
        <g id="sm_ring">
            <path fill="#F1B91B" d="M17.495,15.592c-0.969,0-1.769,0.727-1.891,1.662H14.1c0.125-1.765,1.596-3.158,3.395-3.158c0.532,0,1.036,0.122,1.483,0.34l-0.75,1.303C18.003,15.645,17.755,15.592,17.495,15.592z"/>
            <path fill="#626363" d="M17.495,19.407c0.26,0,0.508-0.052,0.733-0.147l0.75,1.305c-0.447,0.219-0.951,0.34-1.483,0.34c-1.798,0-3.269-1.394-3.395-3.157h1.504C15.726,18.682,16.526,19.407,17.495,19.407z"/>
            <path fill="#626363" d="M19.402,17.506c-0.01-0.617-0.313-1.16-0.773-1.501l0.732-1.316c0.91,0.599,1.521,1.622,1.537,2.794c0.019,1.173-0.559,2.215-1.449,2.841l-0.773-1.293C19.126,18.675,19.413,18.123,19.402,17.506z"/>
        </g>
        <g id="md_ring">
            <path fill="#F1B91B" d="M17.488,13.011c-2.279,0-4.163,1.709-4.447,3.912l-3.54,0.001c0.296-4.154,3.758-7.434,7.987-7.434c1.253,0,2.438,0.288,3.495,0.802l-1.77,3.065C18.684,13.135,18.102,13.011,17.488,13.011z"/>
            <path fill="#626363" d="M17.488,21.989c0.612,0,1.194-0.124,1.727-0.347l1.77,3.064c-1.057,0.514-2.242,0.802-3.495,0.802c-4.229,0-7.691-3.278-7.987-7.433l3.54-0.001C13.325,20.279,15.209,21.989,17.488,21.989z"/>
            <path fill="#626363" d="M21.979,17.501c0-1.452-0.695-2.741-1.769-3.561l1.772-3.071c2.121,1.441,3.517,3.873,3.517,6.632c0,2.758-1.396,5.188-3.517,6.63l-1.772-3.068C21.282,20.241,21.979,18.951,21.979,17.501z"/>
        </g>
        <g id="lg_ring">
            <path fill="#F1B91B" d="M17.476,7.925c-4.862,0-8.88,3.646-9.488,8.345H0.437C1.068,7.409,8.453,0.413,17.476,0.413c2.674,0,5.204,0.615,7.458,1.71l-3.776,6.54C20.021,8.189,18.779,7.925,17.476,7.925z"/>
            <path fill="#626363" d="M17.476,27.075c1.303,0,2.547-0.263,3.682-0.738l3.775,6.54c-2.254,1.096-4.783,1.71-7.458,1.71c-9.023,0-16.408-6.994-17.039-15.856h7.551C8.595,23.43,12.613,27.075,17.476,27.075z"/>
            <path fill="#626363" d="M27.052,17.501c0-3.095-1.483-5.846-3.77-7.597l3.778-6.549c4.528,3.075,7.502,8.262,7.502,14.146c0,5.883-2.974,11.069-7.5,14.144l-3.78-6.547C25.568,23.346,27.052,20.596,27.052,17.501z"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Here is my **CSS Code:**

```
.services-one #lg_ring, .services-one #sm_ring, .services-one #md_ring
{
    -webkit-transition-duration:0.8s;-moz-transition-duration:0.8s;-o-transition-duration:0.8s;transition-duration:0.8s;
    -webkit-transition-property:-webkit-transform;-moz-transition-property:-moz-transform;-o-transition-property:-o-transform;transition-property:transform;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.services-one:hover #lg_ring, .services-one:hover #sm_ring
{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);-moz-transform:rotate(360deg);-o-transform:rotate(360deg);transform:rotate(360deg);
}

.services-one:hover #md_ring
{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-360deg);-moz-transform:rotate(-360deg);-o-transform:rotate(-360deg);transform:rotate(-360deg);
}
```

Here is my **JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/bcdxmpyc/

The top example is the SVG one that I'm attempting to rotate, I want it too rotate just like example below it, but obviously the rings in different directions! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the `transform-origin`

```css
.services-one {
        width: 100px;    height: 100px;
}
.services-one #lg_ring, .services-one #sm_ring, .services-one #md_ring {
    -webkit-transition-duration:0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration:0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration:0.8s;
    transition-duration:0.8s;
    -webkit-transition-property:-webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property:-moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property:-o-transform;
    transition-property:transform;
    overflow:hidden;
    transform-origin:center center; /* here */
}
.services-one:hover #lg_ring, .services-one:hover #sm_ring {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
    transform:rotate(360deg);
}
.services-one:hover #md_ring {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-360deg);
    transform:rotate(-360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="services-one">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 35 35" enable-background="new 0 0 35 35" xml:space="preserve">
        <g id="sm_ring">
            <path fill="#F1B91B" d="M17.495,15.592c-0.969,0-1.769,0.727-1.891,1.662H14.1c0.125-1.765,1.596-3.158,3.395-3.158c0.532,0,1.036,0.122,1.483,0.34l-0.75,1.303C18.003,15.645,17.755,15.592,17.495,15.592z" />
            <path fill="#626363" d="M17.495,19.407c0.26,0,0.508-0.052,0.733-0.147l0.75,1.305c-0.447,0.219-0.951,0.34-1.483,0.34c-1.798,0-3.269-1.394-3.395-3.157h1.504C15.726,18.682,16.526,19.407,17.495,19.407z" />
            <path fill="#626363" d="M19.402,17.506c-0.01-0.617-0.313-1.16-0.773-1.501l0.732-1.316c0.91,0.599,1.521,1.622,1.537,2.794c0.019,1.173-0.559,2.215-1.449,2.841l-0.773-1.293C19.126,18.675,19.413,18.123,19.402,17.506z" />
        </g>
        <g id="md_ring">
            <path fill="#F1B91B" d="M17.488,13.011c-2.279,0-4.163,1.709-4.447,3.912l-3.54,0.001c0.296-4.154,3.758-7.434,7.987-7.434c1.253,0,2.438,0.288,3.495,0.802l-1.77,3.065C18.684,13.135,18.102,13.011,17.488,13.011z" />
            <path fill="#626363" d="M17.488,21.989c0.612,0,1.194-0.124,1.727-0.347l1.77,3.064c-1.057,0.514-2.242,0.802-3.495,0.802c-4.229,0-7.691-3.278-7.987-7.433l3.54-0.001C13.325,20.279,15.209,21.989,17.488,21.989z" />
            <path fill="#626363" d="M21.979,17.501c0-1.452-0.695-2.741-1.769-3.561l1.772-3.071c2.121,1.441,3.517,3.873,3.517,6.632c0,2.758-1.396,5.188-3.517,6.63l-1.772-3.068C21.282,20.241,21.979,18.951,21.979,17.501z" />
        </g>
        <g id="lg_ring">
            <path fill="#F1B91B" d="M17.476,7.925c-4.862,0-8.88,3.646-9.488,8.345H0.437C1.068,7.409,8.453,0.413,17.476,0.413c2.674,0,5.204,0.615,7.458,1.71l-3.776,6.54C20.021,8.189,18.779,7.925,17.476,7.925z" />
            <path fill="#626363" d="M17.476,27.075c1.303,0,2.547-0.263,3.682-0.738l3.775,6.54c-2.254,1.096-4.783,1.71-7.458,1.71c-9.023,0-16.408-6.994-17.039-15.856h7.551C8.595,23.43,12.613,27.075,17.476,27.075z" />
            <path fill="#626363" d="M27.052,17.501c0-3.095-1.483-5.846-3.77-7.597l3.778-6.549c4.528,3.075,7.502,8.262,7.502,14.146c0,5.883-2.974,11.069-7.5,14.144l-3.78-6.547C25.568,23.346,27.052,20.596,27.052,17.501z" />
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Transform-origin does not work very well in Firefox and does nothing in Internet Explorer. You can however get around this problem with using the JavaScript libraries [svgjs](http://svgjs.dev/) or [gsap](http://greensock.com/gsap).

Comment: Hey and thanks, sadly using the code you provided does exactly the same thing http://jsfiddle.net/bcdxmpyc/1/

Comment: Perhaps you could explain in more detail what the problem is.

Comment: it does explain here: `The top example is the SVG one that I'm attempting to rotate, I want it too rotate just like example below it, but obviously the rings in different directions!`

Comment: Yep, just tested and can see its not working in Firefox, also doesn't work in Internet Explorer but I expect that, so whats the problem with Firefox then?

Comment: Well I haven't prefixed the `transform-origin` property so that might be it. Also, I'm not sure that FF & Chrome agree on actual "origin" location so that might be another issue.

Comment: See this article which may provide additional insight [**https://css-tricks.com/svg-animation-on-css-transforms/**](https://css-tricks.com/svg-animation-on-css-transforms/)

Comment: Thanks for your help buddy, I'm now using a gsap method thanks to the article you linked. I've added to your answer at the bottom. You may want to edit what I put ;) thanks again.